# PHP + MySQLi Query post null row

Tags: php

dear Stackoverflow users, I start learning PHP and MySQLi. And now I have some issues. On every page reload in DB added 1 full empty row, every cell is null. Can someone give me advice about issue? Code below:

PHP before **html tag**:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$link = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['link']);

$query = "INSERT INTO demos (name, email, link) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$link')";
$mysqli->query($query);
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

HTML inside **body tag**:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="20" required />
        <input type="text" name="email" required />
        <input type="text" name="link" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: don't allow for empty inputs and/or set your columns to not accept NULL/empty values and apply a header

Comment: Above the $query, add var_dump(array($name, $email, $link)); to see what the values are

Comment: Start with debugging the values, echo them out both before and after escaping them. Then remove the escape code and use `prepared statements` instead. :)

Comment: People [other than myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697278/php-mysqli-query-post-null-row#comment74439311_43697278) aren't getting the question here. *"On every page reload in DB added 1 full empty row, every cell is null."*

Comment: make sure that code is only executed when the form is posted. Wrap it all in a `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` check.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the question is: why on every page load or reload it added 1 empty row? 10 users load page = query adds 10 rows to table.

Comment: @rikoart to which the answer you accepted, did exactly what I suggested you do. And I did "get" the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check if your form is submitted by using [isset](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or ![empty](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

By using isset, you can check wether or not a variable is set:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['link'])) {
    // your code
    }
    ?>
```

By using !empty, you can check if a variable is set and not empty. Note however that if you are using empty you can not submit a '0' or leave a field blank.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['link'])) {
    // your code
    }
    ?>
```

Try using prepared statement for easier use and **protection for SQL injection**:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO demos (name, email, link) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email,$link);
$stmt->execute();
```

Read more about prepared statements: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thank you :) Issue is fixed.

Comment: `!empty()` is better than `isset()`.

Comment: btw; I noticed this received a downvote. I can honestly say that that is not mine. But I have a suspicious feeling as to who did and can't see why they did; it was uncalled for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes empty would work too, but note that if the value of one of the field is empty (or 0) the whole form is not submitted.

Answer (score -1):

Use `var_dump` to debug your code to make sure the values are not null

Add this before and after escaping the strings:

```
var_dump(array($name, $email, $link));
```

Also, switch to using prepared statements

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO demos (name, email, link) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $email, $link);   // bind vars to the parameter
$stmt->execute(); // Execute statement
```